# How should I pass a formula in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a `stored procedure` that has 1 parameter `@MONTH`

I want to set this parameter to this formula:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(GETDATE()))+'0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MONTH(GETDATE())-2)
```

so I'll get something like that: `@MONTH = 201405`.

How do I set the parameter with the formula?

Thanks.

Comment: use a variable. Pass the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MONTH int 
SET @MONTH = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(GETDATE()))+'0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MONTH(GETDATE())-2) 
EXEC YourProcedure @MONTH
```